# Creating an Activity caused Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, xml

The app was just working fine and then I added a new Activity and it started giving me this error. I have tried setting the theme to app compat theme and also using app compat activity. Still nothing working.

```
Process: info.androidhive.loginandregistration, PID: 28764
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.loginandregistration/info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.MainScreenActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:964)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.MainScreenActivity.onCreate(MainScreenActivity.java:69)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
    at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:36)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:185)
    at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:179)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:964) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at info.androidhive.loginandregistration.activity.MainScreenActivity.onCreate(MainScreenActivity.java:69) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
```

Comment: Is your app Theme using one of the `Theme.AppCompat.*` parent?

Comment: yes I'm using 
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library
```

My guess is that:

- When you first created the app, and you created the first activity in the new-project wizard, you unchecked the "Make Backwards Compatible (AppCompat)" checkbox
- When you added your new activity, you did so via the new-activity wizard, and this time you left that checkbox checked

Your overall application theme will not use `Theme.AppCompat`, because you opted out of `appcompat-v7` by unchecking that checkbox. Your new activity is extending `AppCompatActivity`, but it is still using the application theme, and that is a conflict that would generate the error.

Tactically, change your new `MainScreenActivity` to have it extend from `Activity`, not `AppCompatActivity`. You may need to make some other adjustments depending on what activity template you chose and what resources it created (e.g., change `app:` to `android:` on attributes in menu resources).

Strategically, you need to decide whether you want to use `appcompat-v7` or not, then **stick with that choice** for this project. Using `appcompat-v7` gives you a somewhat consistent look-and-feel across Android versions (back to API Level 14), at the cost of your app being ~1MB bigger and some additional complexity when writing the app.